# Center span/text vertically inside h1

Tags: css, center, html

I'd like to center a span element inside a h1 tag. I tried to to set a line-height but it seems to center only the span but not the text next to it. Note: I probably can't use position absolute as the "icon" is not displayed always and it can have different widths.

See the fiddle I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/JJhCY/1/

html:

```
<h1>
    <span class="icon">Icon</span>
    Some Text related to the icon 
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
  .icon 
    {
    background: aqua;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 80%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 40px;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    }


    h1
    {
    background: red;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
    }
```

any idea?

Comment: The easiest way is to set `line-height` of `h1` to its `height` and do not change `line-height` of `span`, like @Vladimir wrote.

Comment: just wanted to check, are you interested in centering vertically or horizontally? if you put the `text-align:center` on your h1 and then add a `<br />` after the span is that the effect you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/cLFka/

Comment: @LukeDuddridge Thanks, but I want to center it vertically

Comment: @kirilloid Thank you. I have the same issue as with Marcs solution, the text inside the span won't center if the font-size is smaller than the one in h1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS basically works.  It is more obvious if you increase the line-height:

see demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/PUeaY/

```css
h1 {
    background: red;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
.icon {
    background: aqua;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: 7px;
}
```

In this example, both the span and the text are vertically aligned in the center, which I think is what you want.

### How This Works...

The CSS engine uses the vertical-align property to align the baseline of the text segments.

In this case, I set the default font-size and line-height for `h1` to 40px and 80px respectively.

For the `.icon`, I reduce the font-size and line-height by 50%.  If `vertical-align` were set to `baseline` or `0`, both the smaller and the larger text would align along the bottom of the letters, but it would not look centered because the icon text has a smaller font size.

By adjusting `vertical-align` to 7px, I got a centering that looks pretty good.  This is not exactly a precise process, but it may work well enough.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but the text inside the span is not centered 100% if the font-size is smaller than the h1 font-size. See here:http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/6356/4pdl.png

Comment: Thanks for your Update, Marc. That's awesome, nice work. I'll test that further. After that I'll mark your answer as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to achieve this would be to use negative margins.

```
span{margin:-4px 10px 0 0} // Uses order of top, right, bottom, left
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but I am not able to center the span with margin. Maybe you can edit my fiddle to explain your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/JJhCY/1/ Thank you.