# Vertically centered child element within header element on same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something simple. I'm trying to have a header tag, that has a child tag with a smaller font size, that is centered vertically, within that header element.  I'm not quite sure how to achieve this.

```
<h2>BIG TITLE: <span>subtitle</span></h2>
```

Comment: They are on two different lines?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616621/center-span-text-vertically-inside-h1

Comment: Is there any particular reason why `vertical-align:middle` doesn't work in your case?

Comment: Reason is you must use display : inline-block / table;

Comment: Why do you have to use `inline-block` or `table`? span elements are `inline` to begin with.

Comment: Ya my bad i am telling for in general for div's. Ya span is for inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```css
h2 span{
  vertical-align: middle; /* you can also use px... */
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>BIG TITLE: <span>subtitle</span></h2>
```

or pick any other desired value from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.